# React: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I've got some data from Firebase Realtime Database and now I'm trying to add it to a variable. I'm sure that the querying works, because if I console.log(dataSnapshot) it logs the correct data (which is 001). However, when I'm trying to create a variable out of that number I get the following error: *Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined* and it doesn't return anything to the console.

Here's my code:

```
class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { timestamps: [], user: auth().currentUser, serial: "" };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const uid = this.state.user.uid;
    console.log(uid);
    let serial = this.state.serial;
    const serialRef = db.ref(uid + "/serial");
    serialRef.once("value").then(function (dataSnapshot) {
      console.log(dataSnapshot.val());
      this.setState({ serial: dataSnapshot.val() }, () => {
        serial = this.state.serial;
        console.log(serial);
      });
    });
```

[Here's the screenshot of my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehNcA.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are having a scope issue: https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-scope/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the callback you pass to `serialRef.once("value").then(...)` does not have a ["this" context](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/#what-is-this-context) set. If you change your code to this, it should work:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    const uid = this.state.user.uid;
    console.log(uid);
    let serial = this.state.serial;
    const serialRef = db.ref(uid + "/serial");
    // grab a reference to the current "this" context
    const table = this;
    serialRef.once("value").then(function (dataSnapshot) {
      console.log(dataSnapshot.val());

      // invoke setState on the captured context
      table.setState({ serial: dataSnapshot.val() }, () => {
        serial = table.state.serial;
        console.log(serial);
      });
    });
```

Or you could use a lambda function, like you already do *in the setState call*:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    const uid = this.state.user.uid;
    console.log(uid);
    let serial = this.state.serial;
    const serialRef = db.ref(uid + "/serial");
     // "Fat arrow" or "lambda" functions implicitly capture the current "this" context
    serialRef.once("value").then((dataSnapshot) => {
      console.log(dataSnapshot.val());
      this.setState({ serial: dataSnapshot.val() }, () => {
        serial = this.state.serial;
        console.log(serial);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This works now. However, if I want to console.log(serial) outside of that function it doesn't log anything.  `serialRef.once("value").then((dataSnapshot) => {
      console.log(dataSnapshot.val());
      this.setState({ serial: dataSnapshot.val() }, () => {
        serial = this.state.serial;
        console.log(serial);
      });
    });
    console.log(this.state.serial);` Do you have any suggestions about how I could use that variable further on in the code?

Comment: I assume you're referring to the last console.log in this comment? In that case, I'm pretty sure it's because both serialRef.once() and this.setState() are _asynchronous_ in nature. Practically what this means is that the execution of your code reaches the last console.log() _before_ the setState completes, so you're trying to log it before the value is set. If you want to ensure that the state is set before doing something, you should do it in the callback of setState, like in your original example.

Answer (score 1):

you are not using arrow callback function, If you don't use arrow callback you have to bind you function. If you don't want to write bind statement use arrow function which will get the context of the class automatically.

```js
serialRef.once("value").then((dataSnapshot) => {
      console.log(dataSnapshot.val());
      this.setState({ serial: dataSnapshot.val() }, () => {
        serial = this.state.serial;
        console.log(serial);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

the arrow function should retain your this context

```
serialRef.once("value").then((dataSnapshot) => {
     console.log(dataSnapshot.val());
     this.setState({ serial: dataSnapshot.val() }, () => {
       serial = this.state.serial;
       console.log(serial);
     });
```